# Is it true that taking injective hull commutes with the tensor product?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, graded-rings, injective-module

Let $M$ and $N$ be two modules (can assume them to be finitely generated if need be) over the ring $A=k[x_0,...,x_n]$. Denote by $E(M)$ the injective hull of $M$. We work in the category of positively graded modules where $\deg x_i=d_i>0$.

My question:

> Is it true that $E(E(M)\otimes_A E(N)) \cong E(M)\otimes_A E(N)$? What hypothesis would be needed to achieve this result?

Comment: If $A$ is Gorenstein, then it is true that the tensor product of injective modules is injective from a theorem of Enochs.

Comment: In general, if $A$ is not Gorenstein, this fails.

Comment: Isn't (the edited version of) your question just asking whether $E(M)\otimes_A E(N)$ is injective?

Comment: @JeremyRickard, yes, in the graded setting.